# What is the meaning of <jxb:bindings version=?

Tags: jaxb, xjc

What are allowed values of version attribute in `jxb:bindings`?

```
<jxb:bindings version="2.0"
              xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
              xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
```

I tried to use different values with xjc "2.2.3-hudson-jaxb-ri-2.2-70-"

```
<jxb:bindings version="2.2"   ... xjc outputs ERROR, only "1.0" is allowed
<jxb:bindings version="2.1"   ... xjc compiled successfully
<jxb:bindings version="2.0"   ... xjc compiled successfully
<jxb:bindings version="1.0"   ... xjc compiled successfully
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The version attribute is used in case there is a change in the bindings between versions of the JAXB specification.  This is necessary to ensure backwards compatibility when using newer implementations of JAXB.  For more information see section 7.1.4 of the JAXB 2.1 specification.

The error message received when specifying version 2.2 I believe is an XJC bug:

```
<jxb:bindings version="2.2"   ... xjc outputs ERROR, only "1.0" is allowed
```

Comment: Thanks, spec  http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/mrel/jsr222/index2.html 
allows only "1.0" and "2.0": 
To indicate this version of the specification, the version 
should be "2.0". It is also valid for @version to be “1.0”. If any other 
version is specified, it must result in an invalid customization as specified in 
Section 7.1.5, “Invalid Customizations.” Error message that only "1.0" is allowed seems to be incorrect.